# Get input from file in integer form

Tags: python

I would like to get data from a file in the int type in python, but error is occuring:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'from sys import argv\n'
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You appear to be attempting to use a Python source file as a number, which is why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
file_descriptor = open('file.name')
bytes = file_descriptor.read()
try:
    newint=int(bytes)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
print(newint)
```

this retrieves data from the file, and tries to parse it into an integer format. (and then prints it back out.)